# Laravel 5.7 Send an email verification on newly created user

Tags: php, laravel, email-verification

Based on this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification) you can easily create a user email verification when someone signing up by them self, but how to send an email verification when admins created the account for their users?

I already tried with this approach

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;

class TeacherController extends Controller
{
    use VerifiesEmails;

    ... // Other basic functions

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'first_name' => ['string', 'required', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['string', 'nullable', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['string', 'required', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['string', 'required', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ];

        $request->validate($rules);

        $teacher = \App\User::create([
            'first_name' => $request->input('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
            'role' => 'teacher',
        ]);

        $teacher->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return redirect()->route('teachers');
    }

    ... // Other basic functions

}
```

but it's not working and no errors at all, but if I use `$request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();` it's working but send email verification for the admin instead. I already googled it but doesn't find the answer I want.

So how to solve this problem? can I achieve it with the default features from laravel or should I created by myself?

EDIT:: Here is the email that coming when i'm using `$request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();`, it's sending to **admin@admin.com** instead **teacher@teacher.com**

[image]

EDIT 2::
I already find the problem, it's because I'm using the `VerifiesEmail` which is the core of the problems I had. Thanks to @nakov for his helps! :D

Comment: let me know what are you using local server and other

Comment: @Krishnakushwaha yes I'm using local server, and using telescope as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `EventServiceProvider` class have you registered the listener for the registered event?

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
];
```

and don't forget to import on top:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
```

Comment: yeah I already did that, but I notice that `SendEmailVerificationNotification()` handling a registered user, but the user that just created is already considered as registered. Here is SendEmailVerificationNotification.php content `public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        if ($event->user instanceof MustVerifyEmail && ! $event->user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            $event->user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
        }
    }`

Comment: well for already registered users, once they log in, if you have surrounded the routes with a verified middleware, it will show them the page to send an email with a link. So the one I mentioned should work for the new users.

Comment: yeah it's true, when they tried to logged in, the need to resent the email verification first, but I don't think it's beauty. So I want as soon as the admin create an account, a email verification will be sent to the newly created account email address

Comment: that's why you should register the listener. But if the admin is registering a teacher, how do they know the password? Even if they receive an email to verify their account they will need to be able to log in into their account?

Do you for some reason override the `to` config in `mail.php` to send mails to `admin@admin.com`?

Comment: they will be given the password that attached to the email, but for now I want to the app send the email verification for each created user **(not from signin up)**.

no I'm not override the email to `admin@admin.com`.

it's sended to `admin@admin.com` is because the logged user for now. is there something I missing if I want to use the default laravel email verification? because their documentation didn't tell us how to use it for another controller, etc.

Comment: I am using the verification not the way you do because I send mails to the users that register themselves but anyway you use `$teacher->sendEmailVerificationNotification();` which should send an email to that user as long as you implement the `MustVerifyEmail` interface in your user class.

Comment: yes, I already implement `MustVerifyEmail`, and it's work fine if someone register themselves. but the case I had is, the user must be registered by the admins. so I kinda stuck with this email verification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185006/discussion-between-nakov-and-khrisna-gunanasurya).