# Laravel verify email responses

Tags: php, laravel

```
    public function resend () {
        if (request()->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Your account is already activated!'
            ], 204);
        }

        request()->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Activation link has been sent to your email.'
        ], 204);
    }
```

Responses after `sendEmailVerificationNotification` are never called, anyone know why?

This is within `VerificationController` from builtin auth module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705417/4575350

Comment: Verification works, just response is always empty. Nothing is returned not even json. But email has been sent

Comment: I can add message on frontend, but I keep trying to get response from backend and display it on the front. Not sure why this does not work on this part of the code only. Before `sendEmailVerificationNotification` every response works

Comment: HTTP Status 204 means: NO CONTENT. Remove it or change it to 200

Comment: @zrkb thats it.